# How can I send javascript as a string in a JSON parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, escaping

I am building dynamic javascript in C# and sending it back to a single page application in a JSON request.

The problem is, the javascript/jquery in the JSON parameter breaks the JSON. How do I properly escape this?

Here is the code... it will combine many small segments of js from files into a string and inject it into a page.

Many thanks!

```
        try
        {   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("dynamic.js"))
            {
                // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                dynamicJS = sr.ReadToEnd();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }


        // user has been authenticated return data and JS to the front end
        return $"{{ \"Email\": \"{userDetails.Email}\", \"DisplayName\": \"{userDetails.DisplayName}\", \"Services\": {safeServices.SerializeToJsonString()}, \"PageElements\": \"{pageURLs}\", \"DyanamicJS\": \"{dynamicJS}\" }}";
```

Comment: Can you post your code so I can try and help?

Comment: Added a code snippet thanks for your help!